# How do you redirect a domain to a subdomain?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect http://www.gelda.com/web_pages/food_index.html to http://food.gelda.com/.

I've tried the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Redirect 301 /web_pages/ http://food.gelda.com/
</IfModule>
```

This didn't work, it redirected to http://food.gelda.com/food_index.html

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gelda.com/web_pages/food_index.html$  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.gelda.com/web_pages/food_index.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://food.gelda.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

This also redirected to http://food.gelda.com/food_index.html

I am not sure what to do in my .htaccess file to make this happen. I need anything in `/web_pages/` to go to `food.gelda.com`.

Comment: I seriously doubt that the second attempt you made redirected anything.

Comment: Are those three host names served by the same http host or not?

Answer (score 0):

Two alternatives based on the rewriting module:

You can use the http servers host configuration (preferred) or a dynamic configuration file in the hosts document root folder (so *parallel* to the `/web_pages` folder):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gelda\.com$  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.gelda\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?web_pages/ http://food.gelda.com/ [R=301]
```

Or you use a dynamic configuration file inside the hosts `/web_pages` folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gelda\.com$  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.gelda\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://food.gelda.com/ [R=301]
```

In all cases the rewriting module needs to be loaded and activated, obviously. If you decide to use a dynamic configuration file (`.htaccess` style file), then you need to enable it's interpretation using the `AllowOverride` directive in the http servers host configuration. Also that file needs to be readable by the server process, obviously.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).